# Does an older widow have to wait before re-marrying?

Tags: halacha, marriage

There is a concept that a widow should wait several months after her husband dies before she remarries in order that the paternity of any children will be obvious.

If the widow is obviously beyond childbearing age, does this requirement apply?

Comment: Hi Avi, just to let you know the way Mi Yodeya works: it is a bit like a community wiki of impersonal questions and answers. Therefore, as your original question was off topic, someone has salvaged it by changing it into an on topic question. Just note that it has become a completely different question now, and answers to it will **not** apply to what you originally asked. Welcome to Mi yodeya!

Comment: See אור זרוע, הלכות יבום וקידושין, ד"ה תנן בהחולץ.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Avi and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 5):

It is actually a machlokes in [Yevomos 42b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.42b.6?lang=bi) between Rebbi Meir who holds that we can't make differences and the same rule applies in every case, and Rebbi Yehuda who allows it. The Halocho is like Rebbi Meir ([Rambam Gerushin 11-20](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Divorce.11.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)); [Even Ho'ezer 13-1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.13?lang=he)

Comment: @Imanonov - I just tidied the links up - feel free to revert if you prefer your way.

Comment: Thank you very much. On the contrary, your links are a lot neater. Don't know how to do it that way.

Comment: You just highlight the relevant text and click on what looks like a linked chain icon and paste the url in. Hatzlocho!

Comment: Thank you very much. Useful knowledge

Comment: @Dov I tried it but can't see a linked chain icon.

Comment: It is in the text tools above the text box

Comment: @Dov - Thank you. I'm clearly missing something. After I highlighted something at, say Sefaria, where do I go from there? Where is that textbox. On Sefaria (can't see it) or here on StackExchange (can't see it either)? And can't see any chain icon either. Sorry to bother you, but I'd like to get it right.

Comment: No @Imanov the tool to link is in Mi Yodeya. In the box you write the answer, there is a few tools at the top e.g. to make bold italic etc. the third icon from the left looks like a linked chain. In your answer where you have written a source, you highlight the words, click on the chain icon and it will open up a box which allows you to the paste in the relevant Sefaria (or other) link.

Comment: Now I'm getting it. Thank you for your patience. The link would still only show the page (in Sefaria etc), not the actual relevant words, I presume. However, in your corrections above, it actually leads to the actual סעיף in the רמב"ם and שו"ע.

Comment: Yes - you need to go on sefaria, find the exact section you want, click on it so it is highlighted, and that creates a new exact link which you can paste in.

Comment: Thank you for all that. (Hopefully) clearer now. Will try it later on an older post. כוח"ט